# How to inherit openpyxl.Workbook and read in an xlsx file into an instance of the inherited class?

Tags: python, oop, openpyxl

I defined a class like so:

```
import openpyxl

class xlWorkbookTeX(openpyxl.Workbook):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        super().__init__()
        self.filename = filename
...
```

My purpose is to extend the `Workbook` class with added functionality (conversion to `LaTeX` tables), and this class seems most appropriate since it has all the functions I need to work with the contained worksheets etc.

But, strangely enough I cannot find a function to read in an existing `xlsx` file **into** the initialised `Workbook` instance **within** the `Workbook` class, although it does have a `save`  method?!

The "official" way to load such data seems to be `openpyx.load_workbook()`, which **returns** a `Workbook` object. But how to get this data in my own `xlWorkbookTeX` instance?

I want to avoid the following:

- add a `Workbook` member (it makes no sense, since I would be referring to a new `Workbook` instance under my inherited object, making the former obsolete)
- copy over (or assigning) all data-holding members from the instance `load_workbook()` returned into my own object (I shouldn't have to care about the internals of the class, that's the reason I inherited from it in the first place)

Am I missing something obvious here? What would be the "correct" way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

#### EDIT:

since this seems less than trivial (let's call it strange architecture of this part of `openpyxl`?), I just took the shortcut I wanted to avoid:

```
def __init__(self, filename):
    super().__init__()
    # ok, awaiting a beter solution, just load and copy the data
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filename, data_only=True)
    self._sheets = wb._sheets
...
```

(This doesn't appear to be an issue since apparently there is no other data loaded than the sheets in my case. YMMV though.)

#### EDIT2:

The complete implementation using this is now at Github: [xls2latex](https://github.com/ppenguin/xls2latex)

Comment: ***"`openpyx.load_workbook()`, returns a Workbook object. how to get in xlWorkbookTeX instance? "***: **You can't**. Possible options: **1.** Rewrite `.load_workbook()` to be a `class xxx(Workbook)` **2.** Mocking `openpyxl` to use your `class xlWorkbookTeX`. **3.** Change your `class xlWorkbookTeX` to compound `Workbook` instead of inherit it.

Comment: @stovfl: By "compound" do you mean adding a member variable to contain the workbook returned by the load function?

Comment: ***"mean adding a member variable"***: Yes.